Error al hacer pnpm run start con angular 17
Tengo un proyecto con angular v17, pnpm v9.6.0 y el node v20.15.1, cuando ejecuto el primer comando pnpm install me instala las dependencias sin presentar ningún tipo de error pero al momento de ejecutar el comando pnpm run start me sale el siguiente error
X [ERROR] Angular compilation initialization failed. [plugin angular-compiler]

  Error: Cannot find package 'C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Nueva carpeta (4)\sumax-erp-frontend-emision-electronica\node_modules\.pnpm\@angular+compiler-cli@17.3.12_@angular+compiler@17.3.12_@angular+core@17.3.12_rxjs@7.8.1_zone_vl5fcjbwx5fdytsb5o3nxnzmha\node_modules\typescript\package.json' imported from C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Nueva carpeta (4)\sumax-erp-frontend-emision-electronica\node_modules\.pnpm\@angular+compiler-cli@17.3.12_@angular+compiler@17.3.12_@angular+core@17.3.12_rxjs@7.8.1_zone_vl5fcjbwx5fdytsb5o3nxnzmha\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\bundles\chunk-NDT2FVCM.js
  Did you mean to import "typescript/lib/typescript.js"?
      at legacyMainResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:215:26)
      at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:841:14)
      at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:927:18)
      at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1169:11)
      at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:383:12)
      at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:352:25)
      at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:227:38)
      at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:87:39)
      at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:86:36)

Este es mi package.json
{
  "name": "Emision-lectronica",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "ng build --configuration=production",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watchAll",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start",
    "lint:fix": "ng lint --fix",
    "format": "prettier --write \"./src/**/*.{ts,json,html}\"",
    "format-lint": "pnpm run format",
    "postinstall": "npx husky install",
    "prepublishOnly": "pinst --disable",
    "postpublish": "pinst --enable"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.3.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.3.10",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.11",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.11",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.3.11",
    "@angular/localize": "^17.3.11",
    "@angular/material": "^17.3.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.11",
    "@angular/router": "^17.3.11",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^17.3.11",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.5.2",
    "@kolkov/angular-editor": "3.0.0-beta.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "16.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "12.0.7",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^17.2.0",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^17.2.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^17.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^17.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^17.2.0",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^4.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.6",
    "@types/object-path": "^0.11.1",
    "@types/toastr": "^2.1.40",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^31.3.2",
    "ag-grid-community": "^31.3.2",
    "bootstrap": "5.3.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "decimal.js": "^10.3.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "ngrx-store-freeze": "^0.2.4",
    "ngx-auto-unsubscribe": "^3.0.1",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "17.1.0",
    "ngx-mask": "^17.0.8",
    "ngx-permissions": "^13.0.1",
    "ngx-sumax-erp-component": "^1.0.7",
    "object-path": "^0.11.5",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.5",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.0",
    "select2": "^4.0.13",
    "sumax": "npm:sumax-erp-schematics@^1.0.25",
    "sweetalert2": "^9.17.2",
    "toastr": "^2.1.4",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.3.8",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "17.5.2",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "17.5.2",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "17.5.2",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "17.5.2",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "17.5.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "^17.3.11",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^17.2.0",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.8",
    "@types/node": "~20.9.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.2.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.2.0",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "jest": "29.7.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "14.1.1",
    "jest-sonar-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "prettier-eslint": "^15.0.1",
    "ts-node": "~10.9.2",
    "typescript": "~5.4.5"
  }
}

Este es mi tsconfig.json
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
        "strict": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "ES2022",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "ES2022",
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": [
      "ES2022",
      "dom"
    ],
        "useDefineForClassFields": false,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "paths": {
            "@core/*": ["@core/*"],
            "~services/*": ["app/core/services/*"],
            "~core/*": ["app/core/*"],
            "~models/*": ["app/shared/models/*"],
            "~shared/*": ["app/shared/*"]
        },
        "types": ["jest"]
    },
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
        "strictInjectionParameters": true,
        "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
        "strictTemplates": true
    }
}


Lo que probé

Valide la correcta instalación de node y de pnpm
Elimine la carpeta node_modules
Borre cache de npm y pnpm
Verifique que en el node_modules se encuentra el archivo en la ruta que especifica el error

Le agradezco de antemano cualquier idea o sugerencia que pueda darme.

Desinstalaste / instalaste el Angular CLI?
